# Custom font (@font-face) and Google font doesn't work in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, font-face

I'm asking this again as I've been through previous answers and have tried their solutions but still it doesn't work on test.

I've got this code on my header that was copied from Google fonts:
`link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

And as I fallback (this project where this will be used might also be offline) I've got this:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'News Cycle';
 src: url('fonts/NewsCycle-Regular.eot?') format('eot'), url('fonts/NewsCycle-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/NewsCycle-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

I've tried both cases individually, separately, have tried [Paul Irish's](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) bullet proof solution, as well as many of the previous answers posted here but all to no vail. It works fine on all browsers apart from IE8 (I can't test IE9, IE10 at the moment but am working on it).

Any suggestions of what could be wrong?

PS: I've also tried other variations of the above code such as:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'News Cycle';
  src: url('fonts/NewsCycle-Regular.eot') format('eot');
}
```

font-family without spaces, without single quotes, changing the location of the files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make a jsfiddle.com where you show the problem?

I have created this example and it works fine in IE8 (just Google Fonts):

http://jsbin.com/omozet/1

Have you tried some of the other solution Paul Irish shows?

Answer (score 0):

you want this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    src: url('font.eot');
    src: url('font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font.svg#font') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The first two lines handle ie6-9; pretty sure the first one is for ie8; you can generate the files and the css even over at fontsquirrel.com